# visual studio highlighting customization

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I am using visual studio 2015 and I am using the 'dark' theme. I like this color layout but there is one thing I want to change. When I click on a word it is surrounded in a box showing me that that is the current word I am on, when I highlight inside of that word there is a very slight color change and I want to make that more pronounced. (see example below, the numbers are the only thing highlighted)

[highlighting example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yMAcK.png)

I dont have any extensions, but I was playing around in tools>options>'fonts and colors' and I was hoping there was an option there that I missed.

EDIT: this was in a javascript file on a variable name, when clicking on a literal like a string there is no surrounding box so the highlighting is more pronounced. Its only when VS highlights the current word in addition to the selected text that produces something like the example.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out
in the tools>options>'fonts and colors' settings you can change the 'selected text ' option and then also the 'highlighted reference' option is the setting that was putting the box around the current word. Both those background colors were similar so it was had to tell what I was currently selecting but you can the colors to be whatever you want to make them more pronounced